# Regex select everything except

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm building a syntax highlighting script and i've got some problems with my regex. I've been failing for about 2 days now so i need help.

I want to select everything that not `/* */` or between them and this is what i got atm, not working tho, but seems close:

```
^(?!(\/\*.*\*\/)$)
```

An example of i want:

```
/* I want to select everything but these comments */
.class-1 {
   font-family: 'SourceCodePro';
   font-size: 16px;
   line-height: 18px;
}
/* I want to select everything but these comments */
.class-2 {
   background-color: rgb(40, 40, 40);
   border: 1px solid rgb(20, 20, 20);
   padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
}
```

I've solved the other regex selections for the rest of the code, but since it's applying to the comments also i need to first select everything but them.

Comment: Where are you checking for the matches?

Comment: I'm logging the matches in the console, if that's what you mean?

Comment: No the function where you are checking the matches and then applying the CSS classes.

Comment: `.replace(/^(?!(\/\*.*\*\/)$)/g, function($1, $2) {
  console.log($1);
  return $1;
})`

Comment: What kind of selection do you want ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use this one:

```
!(/\*.+?\*/)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
!(\/\*(.+)\*\/)
```

i cant check it now.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this https://regex101.com/r/cN5aT1/2

```
/^(?!(\/\*(.+)\*\/)).*/gm
```

It is not working if comments are multiline

Answer (score 0):

Removing comments | **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jS8eh/)**

For single `//` and multiline `/* */`

```
function filter(str)
{

    var regex =/\/\/.+?(?=\n|\r|$)|\/\*[\s\S]+?\*\//g;

    // if you want for multiline only then
    // use var regex =/\/\*.+?\*\//g;

    var temp = str.replace(regex,'');
    alert(temp);
}
```

Comment: I just want to select everything but the comments, not remove them. Then, on that selection, apply the spans for highlighting.

Comment: Select ? to clipboard or what ?